# Is the length of access token in Dropbox authentication constant?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I wanted to know if the length of access token is constant all the time. I'm using OAuth 2 authentication type and want to get the access token from the final redirect URI generated.

I'm trying to do substring of URI to get the access token and want to know if the length is constant.

Comment: Dropbox makes no guarantee that the length of an access token will remain constant. I'd suggest parsing the URI with a real URI parsing function.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204321086-Length-of-AccessToken ]